# Write a recursive function called freq_of(letter, text) that finds the number of occurrences of a specified letter in a string

Tags: python

Write a recursive function called freq_of(letter, text) that finds the number of occurrences of a specified letter in a string.

This function has to be recursive; I may not allowed to use loops! 
My problem is I cannot get "2" in excepted result. Many thanks.

```
def freq_of(letter, text):
    if not letter:
        return 0
    elif letter[0]==text:
        return 1+freq_of(letter[1:],text)
    else:
        return freq_of(letter[1:],text)

Test:
text = 'welcome'
letter = 'e'
result = freq_of(letter, text)
print(f'{text} : {result} {letter}')

Except:
welcome : 2 e
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is that you're slicing `letter` instead of `text`. Try this instead:

```
def freq_of(letter, text):
    if text == "":
        return 0
    elif letter == text[0]:
        return 1 + freq_of(letter, text[1:])
    else:
        return freq_of(letter, text[1:])
```